# Сортировка массива примитивов по убыванию

Tags: java

Как отсортировать массив например int в порядке обратном Arrays.sort.
Как сделать это просто и красиво?
Ничего лучше, чем подсунуть в sort() компаратор не приходит на ум. Но компаратор принимает только массив Integer.

Comment: Про "только массив Integer" -- это откуда? Новые веяния?

Comment: Не совсем верно выразился, собственный компаратор можно использовать только с массивом объектов, но не примитивов.
sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)

Comment: @NikoMart, вообще-то reverse массива примитивов это один проход и 4 строчки кода.

    for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
         int t = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[j];
         arr[j] = t;
    }

Comment: @avp просто мне показалось странным, не обнаружить готового решения по типу примера ниже Arrays.sort(sortedData, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: @NikoMart, для меня это тоже загадка. 

Попробуйте спросить:

*из каких соображений в Java не реализована сортировка примитивов в обратном порядке?*

Вдруг кто-нибудь знает?


--


Возможно это (и наверное многое другое) не сделано только потому, что язык (библиотеки) уже и так перегружены всякой всяченой и Java готова рухнуть под собственной тяжестью.

Иногда складывается впечатление, что Java-программисты тратят больше времени на поиск и изучение готовых решений, чем собственно на написание кода.

Comment: @avp: сравнивая с C# (который тоже не маленький), думаю, тут просто непродуманность системных библиотек. Жаль.

Comment: отсортируй массив и выведи его в обратном порядке

Answer (score 9):

Нет прямого способа сортировки массива примитивов в убывающем порядке. Поэтому у вас в общем есть два пути (без учета возможности реализации собственного алгоритма сортировки):

1. Переход на классы-обертки и использование Collections.sort и Comparator
2. Сортировка примитивов по возрастанию и дополнительные манипуляции с результатом: либо реверс, либо смена логики, использующей результат сортировки (в конце концов результат одной сортировки от другой отличается лишь в направлении прохода по массиву).

Answer (score 8):

> Как сделать это просто и красиво?

```
Arrays.sort(sortedData, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

> компаратор принимает только массив Integer

Это не так. Массив стрингов тоже сортирует:

```
String[] strings = {"d", "e", "b", "a", "c"};
Arrays.sort(strings,Collections.<String>reverseOrder());
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(strings[i] + " ");
}
```

Вывод:

```
e d c b a
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Arrays.sort(sortedData, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: @Gorets, ссылочку на документацию для такой сортировки **примитивов** можно?

IMHO это работает только с массивами объектов (например, Long).

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov для массивов примитивов нет перегруженного метода с компаратором

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно в компораторе результат сравнения умножить на -1:

```
return a.compareTo(b) * (-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без реализации компоратора. Тогда можно будет написать так:

```
//...
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(3);
list.add(2);

Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list);
//...
```

Затем можно использовать:

```
int[] intArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(list.toArray(new Integer[myList.size()]));
```

Правда это все "изврат", проще написать свою сортировку, которая к тому же будет работать быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

в Java8 отсортировать в обратном порядке можно так

`Arrays.parallelSort(array)`

Comment: Это не в обратном порядке, а в несколько потоков.

Answer (score 0):

Без сортировки:

```
int[] newArray = Arrays.stream(myArray)
      // боксим чтобы в sorted() можно было подсунуть компаратор
    .boxed()    
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
      // костыль с Map, иначе в toArray() получим  Object[]
    .mapToInt(x -> x)
    .toArray();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]